# How to extract the value of the alt attribute from the img tag

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm trying to extract the value of the alt attribute from the img tag.

[image]

I want to track title, but not able to track from `img` tag. I have written the below code to track.

```
try:
    Title = webdriver.find_element(By.XPATH, "(//div[@data-dyn='titleArtImage'])").text
    print("Title: " + Title)
except:
    TITLE = "missing title"
```

Comment: Do you want to extract `@alt` value of `img` or to select `div` based on `@alt` value of child `img` node?

Comment: @karthi Firstly, please post HTML in code format; image format would not help to debug generally. Secondly., is there title/text attribute for the img? The content in your image shows just `alt` and `srcset` attributes in the `img` tag, in which case it makes it almost impossible to tell you if you could extract the title from this line. YOu need to provide additional DOM content, or better the website link, if it is ok to share.

Comment: Also, `Title` and `TITLE` are two different variables unless your language is case insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

The value of the `alt` attribute of the descendent *`<img>`* holds the track title.

[image: titletrack]

---

### Solution

To extract the value of the `alt` attribute you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[data-dyn='titleArtImage'] > img"))).get_attribute("alt"))
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@data-dyn='titleArtImage']/img"))).get_attribute("alt"))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```